# Python: getting address of file in bottlepy

Tags: python, html, bottle

How can I get address of file in bottlepy?
I tried it, but it returns %s.shp

```
@get('/upload')
def upload_form():
    return '''
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="filer" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
    '''

@post('/upload')
def upload_submit():
    file_csv = request.get("filer") # I want to get file address (string)
    map = inflation_map.InflationMap(file_csv)
    map.draw_image()
    return file_csv
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do :

```
request.get("filer")
```

you will just get the name of the file. You need to `save` it on to the file system by specifying a path.

It is documented here : http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#file-uploads